# Sqlite: how to split multiple table update into several statements

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join, sql-update

Sqlite update does not support joins. For the following example,

```
update Employee t0 LEFT join EmployeeDetail t1 on (t1.id=t0.id) 
set t0.status=1, t1.salary=t1.salary+10000
where t1.salary < 50000 and t0.status=0
```

The columns to be updated belong to different tables, and they are in where
clause. If split into two statements as the following using subquery:

```
update Employee set status=1
where id in (select t0.id from
Employee t0 LEFT join EmployeeDetail t1 on (t1.id=t0.id) 
where t1.salary < 50000 and t0.status=0)

update EmployeeDetail set salary=salary+10000
where id in (select t1.id from
Employee t0 LEFT join EmployeeDetail t1 on (t1.id=t0.id) 
where t1.salary < 50000 and t0.status=0)
```

Execute one statement will affect the other since it will affect where clause
restriction.

How to workaround this for Sqlite database?

Comment: Which table is `status` in?  You have it in both.

Comment: status in Employee table. updated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest storing the ids you want to update in a temporary table and then using that.  This also prevents race conditions and simplifies locking.

```
create temporary table ids as 
    select e.id
    from Employee e join
         EmployeeDetail ed
         on e.id = ed.id
where ed.salary < 50000 and e.status = 0;
```

Then simply do:

```
update employee e
    set status = 1
    where id in (select id from ids);

update employeedetail
    set salary = salary + 10000
    where id in (select id from ids);
```

Comment: Is there a way to create temporary table in memory and it will be automatically destroyed when transaction ends?

Comment: @Sunnyday . . . Temporary tables are usually handled efficiently in SQLite (https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).